# Get list of Coroutines in current file

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, coroutine, inspect, python-3.8

I want to get a list of all Coroutines in the current file (extern_method and extern_method2 in my code example). The behaviour shall be the same like: `method_list = [extern_method, extern_method2]`, but I want it to be listed automaticly.

I have a file structure like this:

```
@wraps(lambda: extern_method)
@my_decorator
async def extern_method(arg)
return arg + "hello"

@wraps(lambda: extern_method2)
@my_decorator
async def extern_method2(arg)
return arg + 123

class myclass:
    (...)
    def find_extern_methods():
        #here missing code
        return method_list
    (...)
    def do_sth_with_methods():
        #do sth. with Methods
```

I tried to use the `ast` Module:

```
with open(basename(__file__), "rb") as f:
    g = ast.parse(f.read(), basename(__file__))
    for e in g.body:
        if isinstance(e, ast.AsyncFuntionDef):
            method_list.append(e)
```

This may find all Coroutines, but I can't extract any reference to it.

I also tried to use,

```
method_list = inspect.getmembers(basename(__file__), inspect.iscoroutinefunction))
```

but this will not find anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a way to find the Coroutines of the current file itself:

```
my_module_coros = inspect.getmembers(modules[__name__]), inspect.iscoroutinefunction)

coro_list = [coro[1] for coro in my_module_coros if (inspect.getmodule(coro[1]) == modules[__name__]) and coro[0] != "main"]
```

This will return a list of Coroutines, without main itself.